# Is there a way to write Mockito.when(...) to cover all overloads of a method, i.e. return the same thing for any call sharing the same method name?

Tags: java, mockito, overloading

I have a generated class that has a bunch of overloaded methods, *e.g.*

```
Foo create(int)
Foo create(String)
Foo create(int, String)
Foo create(String, String)
Foo create(Foo, int, String)
// ...
// ...
// ...
Foo create(Foo, int, String, Bar, Bar, Bar, Bar, Bar, Bar)
```

Up to 9 parameters.

I know I could just do

```
when(mockedObj.create(any())).return(aThing);
when(mockedObj.create(any(), any())).return(aThing);
when(mockedObj.create(any(), any(), any())).return(aThing);
// ...
// ...
// ...
when(mockedObj.create(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any())).return(aThing);
```

but I wondered if there's a way to just make all overloads of a method return one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a default answer when you mock your type.

From docs of `org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Class<T>, Answer)`:

> Creates mock with a specified strategy for its answers to interactions. It's quite advanced feature and typically you don't need it to write decent tests. However it can be helpful when working with legacy systems.
>
> It is the default answer so it will be used **only when you don't** stub the method call.

So it could be written as:

```
MockedType mockedObj = Mockito.mock(MockedType.class, invocation -> aThing);
```

This will return `aThing` by default.

However, if you need more control, you can use the `invocation` parameter to check that it's actually an overload of `create` that's been called (in particular, to avoid `ClassCastException`s):

```
MockedType mockedObj = Mockito.mock(MockedType.class, 
     (Answer<Foo>) invocation -> 
            invocation.getMethod().getName()
                      .equals("create") ? aThing: null);
```